# The screen gets jumbled when the keypad opens in android

Tags: android, android-layout

In emulator screen not jumped ,
  But when i rum application on mobile phone the screen Jumped

[image]

Here My xml file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/main_bg" >

<!-- Logo -->

<RelativeLayout
 android:id="@+id/main_tabBar"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="40dip"

 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  >
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
android:layout_marginTop="100dip" >

 <!-- JOB DESCRIPTION -->

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_JOB_DESCRIPTION"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:text="@string/job_desc"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="14dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
   </TextView>

  <EditText
     android:id="@+id/edit_JOB_DESCRIPTION11"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_JOB_DESCRIPTION"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true" >
  </EditText>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_JDESCRIPTION"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edit_JOB_DESCRIPTION11"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dip"
    android:text="@string/job_title"
    android:textColor="#4a596e"
    android:textSize="12dip" >
  </TextView>
  <!--  -->


   <!-- LOCATION -->

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_JOB_LOCATION"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_JDESCRIPTION"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_SEARCH"
    android:text="@string/location"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_JOB_LOCATION1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edit_JOB_DESCRIPTION11"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_JDESCRIPTION"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true" >
    </EditText>

   <TextView

    android:id="@+id/txt_JLOCATION"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edit_JOB_LOCATION1"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dip"
    android:text="@string/city_state"
    android:textColor="#4a596e"
    android:textSize="12dip" >
  </TextView>
   <!--  -->


   <!-- JOB ID -->
   <!--  -->


   <!-- SEARCH BUTTON -->

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_search1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_JLOCATION"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
    android:background="@drawable/draw"
    android:text="@string/search" >
   </Button>
  <!--  -->



   </RelativeLayout>

 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
 android:gravity="center"

 android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:weightSum="10"
 android:id="@+id/btnParent" >

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_Login1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/draw"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/login" />

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_register"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/draw"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/register" />
  <!-- 
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_lostlogin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/draw"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Lost Login" />

     -->
  </LinearLayout>

  <TextView
 android:id="@+id/textView2"
 style="flat_detail_name"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/btnParent"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:capitalize="characters"
 android:gravity="center_horizontal"
 android:text="Login or register"
  android:textColor="#000000" />

 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/textView1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_below="@+id/main_tabBar"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
 android:text="@string/get_started_with"
 android:textColor="#000000"
 android:textSize="14dip"    
 android:textStyle="bold" />



 <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                     ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-2584288851778590/4570818460"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
                     ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

In Emulator when i click on EditText then screen not jumped and in mobile phone button and text view jumped and overlap.

Please suggest me how i can fix this problem

Thanks In Advance

Comment: you have designed the layout such that the bottom content will flyover another .... what is your need please explain I will help you out

Comment: when keyboard appear the button and text view don't move up

Comment: try this: android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustNothing" by adding it in the manifest file

Comment: and also improve how your layout is, may be the answer lies there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi deep please follow below step

1) select Activity

2) then select window soft mode from right side pleas scroll it.

3) then select adjustNothing

then you got result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try Using `android:windowSoftInputMode = "adjustResize"` in your manifest file for the activity. Following is a sample activity entry:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".ActivityName"
            android:label="@string/name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue frankly as to how your layout should look like, but having made the following changes to your layout, i found things falling a little bit in place.

changes made:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnParent"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-2584288851778590/4570818460"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"/>
```

and portions of the linear layout to:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:id="@+id/btnParent" >
```

I hope that helps!